# Not enough arguments for a constructor

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm a quite new to scala and playframework.
I have a problem in my code bellow.

```
import play.db.jpa.JPAConfig
import play.db.jpa.JPAEntityManagerContext
import play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi

class MyJPAApiImpl(jpcCfg:JPAConfig, ec:JPAEntityManagerContext) extends 
   DefaultJPAApi {}
```

Every time I compile this code (`sbt compile`), the following error will occur:

```
[error] D:\playground\scala.jpa\app\donuts\jpa\DonutsJPAApi.scala:17:79: not enough arguments for constructor DefaultJPAApi: (x$1: play.db.jpa.JPAConfig, x$2: play.db.jpa.JPAEntityManagerContext)play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.
[error] Unspecified value parameters x$1, x$2.
```

Comment: Where is your constructor call, where you are passing your parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I messed up.
I've just soleved it. I've ignored the scala's basic grammer.

```
class DonutsJPAApiImpl (jpcCfg:JPAConfig, ec:JPAEntityManagerContext) extends 
  DefaultJPAApi(jpcCfg,ec){}
```